# file_get_contents() returns FALSE while simple GET request via Chrome returns JSON data

Tags: php, blockchain.info-api

I'm not sure why am I getting this behavior? I'm trying to implement the Blockchain.com web APIs in my PHP script. Their [documentation states](https://www.blockchain.com/api/api_receive) that I should use `file_get_contents` PHP function to query it, which I do as such:

```
$xpub = "xpub123455";
$callback_url = "https://example.com";
$APIKey = "12345";
$url = "https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive?xpub=".urlencode($xpub).'&callback='.urlencode($callback_url).'&key='.urlencode($APIKey);
//echo("URL: ".htmlentities($url)."<br><br>");
$res = @file_get_contents($url);
if($res)
{
    echo("RES: ".htmlentities(var_export($res, true)));
}
else
{
    $err = error_get_last();
    echo("err: ".($err && isset($err['message']) ? $err['message'] : "-"));
}
```

In that case `file_get_contents` returns `false` and if I then call `error_get_last`, I get the following error:

> err: file_get_contents(-url-): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

But if I just copy the URL that is being passed to `file_get_contents` and [paste it into the address bar](https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive?xpub=xpub123455&callback=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&key=12345) for Chrome:

```
https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive?xpub=xpub123455&callback=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&key=12345
```

it returns a valid JSON data:

[image]

Why are these two outputs different? And how can I get a JSON response from `file_get_contents`?

Comment: That endpoint probably checks the User-Agent of the request, for anything that resembles an actual, current browser - and if that’s not present, it rejects the request (or requires additional authentication, maybe.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: Use the Chrome inspector to see what the HTTP request has (header, etc.), and make a similar request using curl (there are a lot of curl options for that). https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

The allow_url_fopen function is probably restricted.

It is better to use cURL instead of file_get_contents:

```
function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

then you can use this function:

```
$res = @url_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Should there be some sort of a `try`/`catch` section there?

Comment: _“The allow_url_fopen function is probably restricted”_ - that’s of course absolutely not the issue here. If that was the case, it would not even get as far as getting an actual HTTP response code. Plus, the error message would pretty clearly say if this was the case.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. For example, why do you suppress the errors thrown by cURL?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question:

> And how can I get a JSON response from file_get_contents?

You can obtain a json response from `file_get_contents` with (I added a `http.ignore_errors` flag here, this will prevent PHP from throwing an error):

```php
$xpub = "xpub123455";
$callback_url = "https://example.com";
$APIKey = "12345";
$url = "https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive?xpub=".urlencode($xpub).'&callback='.urlencode($callback_url).'&key='.urlencode($APIKey);

//add http.ignore_errors flag here 
$res = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create([
    "http" => [
      'ignore_errors' => true
    ]
]));

/*
 * string(40) "{message" : "API Key is not valid"}"
 */
var_dump($res);
```

Could you share the api key since helping is a bit difficult since you must go through a review process before you get an api key. And therefor it is not possible to reproduce the error.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?